# Getting the spid of a Powerbuilder database Connection?

Tags: powerbuilder, spid

I've been trying to find some manual information on this, but my search is fruitless.

I'm trying to see if there is a way to find the unique spid (from sp_who) of a connection into a database from Powerbuilder.

As in, a user logs in, and I can see their sp_who record, but I want to be able to obtain and manipulate this id in the application itself.

*(This is probably an easy one. Free rep, pb experts!)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, after trying to google this again this morning (and getting this question as the first result :p) I've found that there's actually a `@@SPID` variable that I can call.

What I've done is create a procedure

```
create procedure prc_get_spid
as
begin
return @@spid
end
```

then in my application I just go

```
long ll_spid
ll_spid = sqlca.prc_get_spid()
```

which gives me the spid for the sqlca connection.

^_^

Answer (score 0):

Another way of accessing the SPID without creating a stored procedure is access it from within a derived table as shown below.

```
SELECT ses.SPID
INTO :SPID
FROM (SELECT SPID = @@SPID) AS ses
USING SQLCA;
```